# How I can use Twig on Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, twig

How I can use Twig on Codeigniter? 
I want to install twig with composer then use twig in my project but i can't do it.
please tell me step by step, thanks.

Comment: Why can't you do it? Why not just look at the documentation? This is a Q&A site, not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, it can be tricky to configure but just load twig as a library.

Here is the repository I use for my CI project with Twig: https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig

Comment: i installed this configuration: 
### Installation With Composer and then in controllers/welcome.php used this codes:
  `$this->load->library('twig');
  $data = 'welcome to codeigniter !';
  $this->twig->display('welcome_message', $data);`

  then in welcome_message.php writed 
  `{{ data }}`
  but has an error:
**Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\CITwigWithComposer\application\libraries\Twig.php on line 94**
  hot to fix it?